# Mac Shell - Command works in Terminal but not in Shell

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am currently working on a shell script for a small business Mac environment.  The intention of the script is to add a few applications to the dock.

I can run the commands via terminal individually, but I am unable to run them in a shell script.  The script only completes the "killall Dock" command, no errors or warnings.

This is the code I attempted:

```
#!/bin/sh
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/Firefox.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/Calculator.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Users/Shared/RMS.fmp12</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'

killall Dock
exit 0
```

Update:

I attempted to execute the 'defaults' command while in bash (i.e 'sudo bash') and it does not appear to have any effect.

When I run the exact same command in a normal terminal it works.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/Firefox.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'
```

Comment: Terminal runs the shell. You need to be more specific about when the script fails.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  I assume when you say "running the script", you mean running them from Terminal while logged-in normally?

Comment: I can type each line of that shell script into a terminal window, while logged in as an administrator and each line works individually.

When I place each line into a shell script and attempt to execute the shell script via terminal.  i.e. "sudo ./script.sh"  only the killall Dock command seems to work, nothing else changes.

Comment: How about doing `sudo bash` and then `./script.sh`?

Comment: Had you try to change the first line to #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: I attempted both, and reattempted just now, still with no effect.

Comment: Does the command fail in the terminal as well if you put `sudo ` in front of it?

Comment: I just checked, but yes, it fails if sudo is placed in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

The defaults command changes settings for a particular user. When you use sudo you run the defaults command, not as the current user, but as a different user (i.e. root).

From your description it sounds like defaults is changing the settings for the root user (because that is who sudo makes it run as) so when Dock is restarted (and run as the current user) it doesn't see any settings changes.

There should be no reason to use sudo in your particular case. A user can change their own settings with no special permissions and Dock is also run as the current user and so can be killed. Therefore just run the script (e.g. `sh script.sh`) and it should work.

Should you still have problems then I would come back with exactly what you are typing and the output of `defaults read ...` after running.

Comment: I also see the same behavior. In my case, I actually sleep for a few seconds, and then read the value back. Also, I am not switching users.

Running "defaults write" inside of a shell script has no effect.